# What should I do overall after an update creates a login loop

Tags: dual-boot, login

First, before detailing the problem, can I say I have searched through the archives and realise that there are tons of related answers so I think I can find out how to do stuff.  I need advice as to what I should do.

I have a Goliath PC, 16Gb with an Intel® Core™ i7-4790K processor, graphics GeForce GTX 980/PCIe/SSE2, two discs, 480Gb SSD and a 2 Tb hard drive.  It came with Windows and I installed Ubuntu as a dual boot with no apparent problems, until now.

I always install recommended updates, including the latest releases (so I am on 16.10).  The last update I installed required a reboot which then hung on the logon screen (with no drum roll audio).  I managed to use the on-screen keyboard and entered the password and found myself in the logon loop.  I needed to finish some critical work, so rebooted the machine using the previous version of Ubuntu on the grub(?) screen.  Thankfully it worked.

I decided to back up my home directory, before doing anything else and discovered that my version of Ubuntu is installed on the hard drive not the SSD, which explained the sluggish boot compared to windows.

So should I:

1. Install a new Ubuntu on the SSD (which is where I wanted it originally)? It is appropriately partitioned.  If I do, should I wait a couple of weeks for the new release 17.04?  What will the grub screen look like and will it be easy to distinguish the SSD version?  After the install, can I go back to the version -1 I am using at the moment if I have to.
2. Should I use the -1 version and implement the changes queuing up?
3. Should I try and sort out the loop first?  I am not very command line savvy.

Thank you for your advice in advance.

John Amiry

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do overall after an update creates a login loop

- reboot using the older kernel.

> so rebooted the machine using the previous version of Ubuntu on the grub(?) screen.

- Good choice :)

Start up a terminal session and head over to `/var/log` and start examining the logs. Do a `ls -ltr` 1st to see what log got changed and use tools like `more`, `less` to find the lines that indicated a problem (scan for words like "error", "critical", "retry"). Most likely there is a repetitive action inside these logs (a log that has become rather large over a small period is an indication of a log that needs examining). When you find one google it and see if it has a fix, apply the fix and reboot.

If all goes well you fixed the problem.

If not you can still re-install. But a re-install might bring back the same problem so besides time consuming it might also not be a fix.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice on handling logs, very useful.  I may not have explained properly but I would like to re-install (if that is possible)  so it boots from the SSD but I am unsure what effect that has on the initial screen.